# Select all except top N in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data that I don't need to keep for very long, so every night I want to remove all rows except the last 20.

To do that, I found the following query:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT TOP 10 ID FROM Table
    ) AS x
)
```

MySQL doesn't support the TOP function, so I rewrote it to use LIMIT instead:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT ID FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10
    ) AS x
)
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't seem to support the LIMIT function within subqueries. So what do I do now?

**How do I select all except the 10 rows with the highest ID?**

I could probably just delete all the records that are older than a day or something, but it feels like I *should* be able to do it this way.

Comment: that query runs fine for me, which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: 5.1.41, and I'm not able to upgrade.

Comment: I was testing on 5.1.49 and wouldn't have thought it was much different. Does it give an error message or simply the wrong result?

Comment: @araqnid - did the select run fine, or did you try the whole thing, including the delete?  I know MySQL is funny about reading from and writing to the same table.

Comment: My bad. The query works now. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong, but it works flawlessly now. I guess limit inside subqueries does work in this version of mysql (I never checked which version it was introduced in).

Comment: I put 12 rows into a test table (MyISAM), ran the delete, and the lowest-numbered two rows had been deleted.

Comment: oh, I think you should just delete record older than a day, is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
DELETE t
FROM 
    TableX AS t
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT Id
      FROM TableX
      ORDER BY Id DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
    ) AS tenth
WHERE t.Id < tenth.id
```

Comment: Are you sure MySQL will allow it?  Don't you need to nest the sub-query one level deeper because of MySQL's foibles about reading and writing the same table at the same time?

Comment: @Dems: It works fine. The 2-level nesting is needed when you use the table (you are deleting from) in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Or when you want to have `IN (SELECT ... LIMIT n)`

Answer (score 2):

As MySQL has foibles when reading from the same table as you are deleting, the simplest option is often to use a temp table.

```
INSERT INTO yourTempTable
SELECT id FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10

DELETE yourTable WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM yourTempTable)
```

Or many variations thereof (using joins instead of IN, etc).

The main consideration isn't about how to write the second query, it's about race conditions.

Your data could be changed by another process between the temp table and the delete.  If that is possible and matters, you need to wrap it all in a transaction and slap a table lock on `yourTable`.

Comment: i think the 2nd query should be a NOT IN

Comment: @Dems: There is a subtle issue with the temp table approach. Between the Insert into the temp table and the Delete operation, new rows may have been added and will get deleted, too.

Comment: @ypercube - Isn't that what the last two sentances address?

Comment: @Dems: Oh sorry, I don't know how I missed that. I think the "slap a table lock" expression got me confused.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this, I would prefer this :-

```
 create table tmp_table select * from your_table order by id desc limit 20;
 truncate table your_table;
 insert into your_table select * from tmp_table;
 drop table tmp_table;
```

It seems very lengthy at first glance,
but personally I think is understandable,
and very low risk (plus, it should be efficient that doing a JOIN)

PS : truncate won't reset auto increment field

ps2 : this approach assume there is no write during truncate, one can issue lock to preserve the data integrity

Comment: Truncating and re-inserting is a pretty intense way of doing that...  And as you mention, it kills autoincrement, and by implication foreign keys, etc, etc.

Comment: it does not kill auto increment, truncate is not intense (much faster that delete with select), plus it only insert 20 records. and OP did not mentioned is innodb.

Comment: @ajreal - Oh yeah, 20 records.  But if it was 10m, this would be intense ;)  *[And the autoincrement breakage is cause by all the records getting new ids (you don't explain how to get around that) and the truncate busting any foreign key.]*

Comment: @Dems truncate is design to quick delete everything. in either scenario, the foreign key will busted. The truncate does not reset the autoincrement